# BLE Nano using Arduino Ide issue

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

Hi I'm trying to load  sample blink application on BLE Nano device using Arduino Ide. It starts compiling but than it crashes with

```
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
    at processing.app.debug.Compiler.compileHex(Compiler.java:793)
    at processing.app.debug.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:148)
    at processing.app.Sketch.build(Sketch.java:1589)
    at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1611)
    at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1597)
    at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2397)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.app.helpers.StringReplacer.replaceFromMapping(StringReplacer.java:97)
    at processing.app.helpers.StringReplacer.replaceFromMapping(StringReplacer.java:89)
    at processing.app.helpers.StringReplacer.formatAndSplit(StringReplacer.java:37)
    at processing.app.debug.Compiler.compileHex(Compiler.java:791)
    ... 6 more`enter code here`
```

So the question is. What is the reason of this crash. And how to fix it?

UPDATE:
I've used http://redbearlab.com/getting-started-nrf51822/ to configure connection.
Here is sample code:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the sample code it's importing? Also, can you see the board in the ports as a COMM#? I have an inkling that the installation process of the IDE might not have occurred correctly, cause some components/libraries to be missing. This can potentially cause the problems you're describing, IF you're sure that your board is connected correctly and all you're doing is importing a sample code.